# What kind of cookies does amazon affiliates use

Tags: cookies, amazon-web-services, affiliate

So i've been playing around with the amazon affiliates program recently. I've looked on their site as i click through with my link, but can't seem to find the cookie that stores my affiliate identifier. is their affiliate cookie stored on the server, or is it stored on the user's computer. Any insight into this would be awesome. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As a rule, a cookie will be dropped on user's computer to keep track of whether they make a purchase or not through your affiliate link. Generally the lifespan of an affiliate cookie varies depending upon the affiliate program. For example, with Amazon, you can have a 24 hour cookie or 90 day cookie. Also I would recommend that you check [Amazon Affiliate club](http://amazonaffiliate.club). It is some kind of community where you may find many useful tips about Amazon affiliate program!